# Authentication problem when updating private submodule within github actions

Tags: github, git-submodules, github-actions

My repository includes a submodule, the submodule is a private repository.
Whenever a push happens, a test-script is executed using **GitHub actions**.
When **GitHub actions** updates the submodule, it runs into an authentication problem and cannot access the submodule with GitHub actions.

I followed the discussion on how to authenticate to private repositories, [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116) and [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/81).

Currently, my main issue is how to access and use the personal access token as discussed in the links above.

One of discussion contributors uses a `secret.GITHUB_PAT` variable, the other one uses `secret.CI_PAT`.
Following [this github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow), there might be a `secret.GITHUB_TOKEN` but I have no idea how they created the other two.

-> Are they all the same? How do I create these variables and how do I get my correct PAT put into these variables?

Naively running the code from [Lauszus reply](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/116#issuecomment-573660416) gives me the following error.

**My Code**
assuming `SUBREPO` is the submodule,

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout reposistory
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Checkout submodule
      run: |
      git config --file=.gitmodules SUBREPO.url https://${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/COMP/SUBREPO.git
      git submodule sync
      git submodule update --init --recursive
```

**Output**

```
Run git config --file=.gitmodules SUBREPO.url ***github.com/COMP/SUBREPO.git
  git config --file=.gitmodules SUBREPO.url ***github.com/COMP/SUBREPO.git
  git submodule sync
  git submodule update --init --recursive
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
Submodule 'SUBREPO' (https://github.com/COMP/SUBREPO.git) registered for path 'MYREPO/SUBREPO'
Cloning into '/home/runner/work/MYREPO/MYREPO/MYREPO/SUBREPO'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/COMP/SUBREPO.git' into submodule path '/home/runner/work/MYREPO/MYREPO/MYREPO/SUBREPO' failed
Failed to clone 'MYREPO/SUBREPO'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into '/home/runner/work/MYREPO/MYREPO/MYREPO/SUBREPO'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/COMP/SUBREPO.git' into submodule path '/home/runner/work/MYREPO/MYREPO/MYREPO/SUBREPO' failed
Failed to clone 'MYREPO/SUBREPO' a second time, aborting
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main issue was the **secrets** from GitHub, which can be found at settings within ones repository, see picture attached [secret setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFKD4.png). I added my PAT as a secret with name <PAT>, so GitHub actions can access it via ${{ secret.<PAT> }}

I further updated my code to use my PAT as follows,

**Submodule Code-part for GitHub actions**

```
  uses: actions/checkout@v2.0.0
  with:
    token: '${{ secrets.<PAT> }}'
    repository: <COMP>/<SUBMOD>
    path: <relative_path_to_submod>
    ref: '<branch>'
```

**End of workflow Output**

```
From https://github.com/<COMP>/<SUBMOD>
* [new branch]      <branch>        -> origin/<branch>
/usr/bin/git branch --list --remote origin/<branch> origin/<branch>
/usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force -B <branch> refs/remotes/origin/<branch>
Switched to a new branch '<branch>'
Branch '<branch>' set up to track remote branch '<branch>' from 'origin'.
```

<COMP> and <SUBMOD> are the user and the submodule repository. <branch> refers to the branch of the submodule you'd like to be tracking.